# Function to bring number below a certain number

Tags: python

I have a function in which i get 2 numbers and add 75 to it, i dont want the resultant number to exceed 275, is there a python function that can do this for me, the code is like below,

```
def newnumber(num1,num2):
    numbers = num1+num2+75    
    if numbers >275:
            numbers = numbers - 275;
    else:
            numbers 
    return numbers
```

Above code just does it once, i want it sort of looped or if there is any python builtin function that can do this, it will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to use a `while` loop?

```py
def newnumber(num1, num2):
    numbers = num1 + num2 + 75    
    while numbers > 275:
        numbers -= 275
    return numbers
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `mod`

```py
def newnumber(num1,num2):
    numbers = num1+num2+75
    numbers = numbers % 275
    return numbers
```

If you want to select the smaller one between `numbers` or `275`, you can use `min`

```py
def newnumber(num1,num2):
    numbers = num1+num2+75
    numbers = min(numbers, 275)
    return numbers
```